# Stata Mata Programming Conformability Error

Tags: matrix, stata

Hi I need help in Stata's Mata programming language for the following Minimum Working Example.

I am trying to insert sub-matrices of dimension (1x200) (generated by a random normal draw) inside a pointer matrix of dimension 600x1 (V matrix).

```
mata:
T=600     //number of markets
K_S=1    //number of variables with stochastic coefficients
R=200   //number of random draws
st_matrix("T", T)
//pointers to the market specific random draws:
V=J(T,1,NULL)   //   T by 1  0 matrix

for(t=1;t<=T;t++){ 
V[t]=(rnormal(K_S,R,0,1)) //dimension K_S x R
}
end
```

The problem is I am getting a "rnormal():  3200  conformability error"

Could you suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I can't get past `st_matrix("T", 600)`  in your case, which creates a matrix in Stata (NB) which is 1 x 1 and holds the constant 600. What is the point of that? This looks like the XY problem to me. Do you need a matrix that is 600 x 200 at any one time? If so, why not produce it directly? Why are pointers needed? http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a `K_S x R` matrix to a single cell in a column vector. A pointer has to be assigned, well, a pointer:

```
mata:
T   = 600 // number of markets
K_S = 1   // number of variables with stochastic coefficients
R   = 200 // number of random draws
st_matrix("T", T)

// pointers to the market specific random draws:
V = J(T, 1, NULL)  // T by 1  0 matrix

for(t=1; t<=T; t++){ 
    V[t]= &(rnormal(K_S, R, 0, 1)) //dimension K_S x R
}
end
```

In mata the `&` notation means pointer.

Comment: Thank you Mauricio. So I tried the correction and I am getting this result.. 
     mata: V
                 1
      +-------------+
    1 |  0xfa7f240  |
    2 |  0xfa81cc0  |
    3 |  0xfa80890  |
    4 |  0xfa82320  |
    5 |  0xfa82980  |
    6 |  0xfa82870  |
    7 |  0xfa82760  |
    8 |  0xfa82210  |
    9 |  0xfa81880  |
   10 |  0xfa81990  |
   11 |  0xfa80670  |                                                 Could you tell me  What does this mean? I thought i would get a submatrix  of dimension K_SxR in a Column Vector of 600x1. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ska No. You have created 600 + 1 objects. One 600 x 1 vector and 600 K_S x R matrices. A pointer is just an address, literally. So V is a vector with 600 addresses and the actual objects are somewhere else. Where are they? For instance, V[1] is "0xfa7f240", which is the address of the K_S x R matrix in memory. You can refer to them via *V[1], *V[2], and so on.